# Identify this television series where pilot massages his own heart?

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to locate this television series (I'm almost positive it was series) for years. I only distinctly remember one scene where a pilot of a small space fighter (a heavy set guy that might have robotic parts) has some sort of cardiac attack and he opens his flight suit and can directly massage his heart to return it to normal function. I guess that being able to do that suggests it is his heart that's robotic... but I can't be certain.

This is almost certainly not older than 20 years, and not more recent than the last 10, possibly even 15.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is almost certainly [Space Rangers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106144/?ref_=sr_1), a 6-episode sci-fi series from 1993.
Doc Kreuger (played by Jack McGee (who matches your description to a T), who has "left more body parts on more planets than he cares to remember" has, among other things, a removable artificial heart (see episode 1, approximately 15 minutes in).
The episode list at IMDB is not particularly helpful, and the list at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Rangers_%28TV_series%29) is only marginally better, as it has more info. I can't tell you which specific episode the heart-massage occurs, as I haven't watched the series in about 2 years, but I also distinctly recall this incident. I think it may be episode 2 or 3.

Comment: YES! This is definitely it, I recognize the actor. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of service.