# SF TV series where fighter pilots lay prone to fly their ships

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a science fiction TV series.  The only thing that I can tell you for sure is that it was situated in space and that the fighter pilots had to lie prone on their stomachs to fly the fighter ships. Their heads were towards the front of their fighters. There was a war with an alien species.

Comment: there isn't a lot of detail here - when did you see the show? what kind of budget was it?

Comment: Was it English language?

Comment: Asker isn't logging-in after posting.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/identify-this-television-series-where-pilot-massages-his-own-heart

Comment: This is just a bit too broad. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 6):

The only one I can think of that comes to mind is Babylon 5 - the Minbari fighters had their pilots lying prone and facing the front of the ship. Some of these were piloted by humans in the series, too.

But I can't find a screenshot of a pilot in place at the moment.

However, take a gander at https://www.google.com.au/search?q=babylon+5&hl=en&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=jD3mUPLxAuq4iQe36oGoAQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAA&biw=1920&bih=1063 and see if any of that jogs your memory

Comment: Also, the Shadow-fighters' pilots are lying down.

Comment: the only couple of times you see Shadow pilots, they simply seem to standing inside fighter with their limbs spread starlike

Comment: The ships fly with the pilots oriented headfirst.

Comment: hmm.. i can't find a screenshot easily on Google, and all of my DVDs are boxed up ready to move, but i'm pretty sure they're upright

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if you're not thinking of [Space Rangers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106144/).
It's more of a police/paramilitary series, but the ship is piloted from a belly-down prone position, and there is a background of a war with an alien race, the Banshee.
They only made six episodes, but it was rather enjoyable- kind of a spiritual precursor to Babylon 5, in a way.

Answer (score 3):

There is an episode of [Battlestar Galactica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica_%282004_TV_series%29) ([You can't go home again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Can%27t_Go_Home_Again_%28Battlestar_Galactica%29)) where Starbuck drives a Cylon fighter that way... maybe you watched that episode?